# Destructuring tuples in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, tuples, destructuring

I'm trying to destructure a tuple:

```
tuple = [[1,"word",3,4,5],[1,"hello",3,4,5],[1,"word",3,4,5]]
```

Like so:

```
let destruct = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5] = [tuple]
```

But  everything gets assigned to `item1` from the tuple. Is it possible to actually map each array from the tuple to the 5 items in the second array?

Expected output:

```
item2[0] = "word",
item2[1] = "hello
```

EDIT: someone answered with a tuples.map which got the desired result, but the answer has been deleted? Furthermore, is a pure destructing solution possible?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - What is your expected output?

Comment: Can you please show the wanted output?

Comment: Regarding your edit: I removed the answer because it was not working due to the amount of items being larger then the amount of arrays. Fixed it and un-deleted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71665522/5625547)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), get the index from the first, en use that to create each 'column':

```js
const [ ] = tuple[0].map((_, i) => tuple.map((_, j) => tuple[j][i]))
```

```js
const tuple = [[1,"word",3,4,5],[1,"hello",3,4,5],[1,"word",3,4,5]];

const [ item1, item2, item3, item4, item5 ] = tuple[0].map((_, i) => tuple.map((_, j) => tuple[j][i]));

console.log(item2[0], item2[1]); // word hello
console.log(item4);              // [ 4, 4, 4 ]
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, is this the simplest way to do it?

Comment: Yea, don't think there is a 'cleaner' way of doing this without any external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You have extra brackets around tuple, try this

```js
const tuple = [[1,"word",3,4,5],[2,"word",3,4,5],[3,"word",3,4,5]]
const [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5] = tuple

console.log(item3)
```

Comment: That maps the a single array in the tuple to a single item, so `item1  = [1,"word",3,4,5]`  I need `item1[0] = 1`

Answer (score 0):

you can destructure any array or object in javascript

```
let tuple = [[1,"word",3,4,5],[1,"word",3,4,5],[1,"word",3,4,5]]

let [item1, item2, item3] = tuple
```

you can even get the nested value as follows

```
let [item1, [one, word, three], item3] = tuple;
console.log(one)  // 1
console.log(word)  // 'word'
console.log(three)  // 3
```